# DynamoDB table structure for user-groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to create a dynamoDB table structure that will model users and groups of an application.

Conditions:

- Each user/group are part of an application
- Each group can have multiple users
- Each user can be in multiple groups
- Users can be in groups or not
- Groups can be empty

I think I have a pretty relational thinking and I'm curious if you can model something like this in Dynamo.

I thought of something like this:

> Table: appId(PK) groupName(SK) username(SK) details1 details2

but I see that you can have only one PK and one SK in dynamo

Then I thought of something like this:

> Table: appId(PK) groupName#username(SK) details1 details2

but this doesn't seem like a good idea (groups can have no users, users can have no groups and I don't know how to get all users from a group for example)

How would you model something like this in Dynamo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends a lot on what queries you need to support on your data, which is something you have to think about a lot more carefully in a NoSQL model than you do in a relational model.

Personally I would probably start by having two tables, for groups and users, each keyed by appId (PK) and groupId/userId (SK), with other properties for details. Then in the users table I would have a field userGroups as a StringSet containing the list of ids of groups the user is in.  This gives you the ability to query:

- All users in a given application
- All groups in a given application
- All groups for a given user in a given application (hence whether a given user is in a particular group)

If doing the final query (all users for a given group in a given application) is a rare occurrence (or the number of users per application is small), you can do a Scan operation on the users table keyed by the appId and filtering on the userGroups field.  If the performance of that query is more important, but the number of users per group is not too large, you could have a mirror groupUsers StringSet field in the groups table as a mirror, and keep the two fields in sync either at the application level, or by replicating from one to the other using DynamoDb Streams.

Or you could separate off the mapping into a separate table, much the same as you would in a relational database.  You would key this table by appId(PK) userId(SK), and then create a Global Secondary index on appId(PK) groupId(SK) to allow querying in the other direction.  AWS will keep the index up to date with any changes in the data.

Comment: I also started with two tables: one for groups and one for users

Comment: In the table for groups: ```appId, group, groupDetails```
In the table for users: ```appId, username, group, userDetails, groupDetails```

But then I thought of having one table(and two GSI appId-group, appId-username):```appId, id, group, username, groupDetails, userDetails```
This way you can search by group, by user, by app

Comment: What I am not sure now if I should also add groupDetails to each user to improve the query performance.  

- If I add groupDetails to each user: query more performant, but update group will imply updating all users  

- If I don't add groupDetails to users(only group name): I will need to do two queries to get groupDetails per user, but updating groupDetails will not imply updating users.  

Any thoughts on this? Thank you

Comment: This one combined table sounds pretty complicated, and also sacrificing many of the interesting properties of ddb tables (you're increasingly just looking at a document store partitioned by `appId`.  What advantages do you get from combining everything into one table?

Comment: From what I understand in Dynamo you should agregate properties.. not normalize them,

I changed the structure based on this topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-adjacency-graphs.html

Comment: I am trying to see the advantages myself..because the above topic seems to say that the appropriate design would be one table..also many of the presentations that I saw like this one:  
```https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDQ3jbDyTQ4&feature=youtu.be  ```
The only advantage that I currently see is that the queries would be a little faster and I won't have to go in two tables to agregate the data myself by making multiple queries.

Comment: Are you referring to the Adjacency List pattern or the Materialised Graph pattern?

Comment: adjancency list pattern